# How do you simplify the addition of square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, arithmetic

$2\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{3}$

How do I simplify this?

Comment: It can’t be simplified any further.

Comment: Check the edit. I left something out.

Comment: That doesn't make it any better.

Comment: Brian's comment still applies, even after your edit.

Comment: Okay well thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you perhaps intended to solve the equation $2\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{3} = 0$?

Comment: What's not simple about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are searching for something similar to this:

$$\sqrt{a{^+ _-}\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{a+c}{2}}{^+ _-}\sqrt{\frac{a-c}{2}}$$

$$c=\sqrt{a^2-b}$$

A example:

$\sqrt{5{^+_-}\sqrt{24}}=\sqrt{\frac{5+1}{2}}{^+_-}\sqrt{\frac{5-1}{2}}=\sqrt{3}{^+_-}\sqrt{2}$

In your problem:

$2\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4x}$

$a+c=2\times3$

$a-c=2\times4x$

So,

$a=4x+3$

$c=3-4x$

$b=a^2-c^2=(a-c)(a+c)=8x\times6=48x=3x\times4^2$

The final is:

$$2\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{4x+3+4\sqrt{3x}}$$

But it needs a better investigation of the existence conditions in these calculus.

Comment: I haven't followed the details of the calculations, but how is the final result supposed to be *simpler* than $2\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{3}$?

Comment: It's no simpler (I wrote *Maybe you are searching for something similar to this:*), it's just a transformation and maybe was he is looking for. If he tells not I'll delete if none think this useful.

Comment: Compare with my [Simple Denesting Formula.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/90503/242)

Answer (score 2):

This seems a simpler derivation to me:

Squaring $a \sqrt x + \sqrt b$
we get
$a^2 x + b + 2a \sqrt{bx}$
so
$$ a \sqrt x + \sqrt b = \sqrt{a^2 x + b + 2a \sqrt{bx}}.
$$

This seems to be a more complicated result to me.

I know, it's all about me.