# How to solve $\sqrt{9-4\sqrt{5}}=$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals, nested-radicals

Need some hints how to solve this: $\sqrt{9-4\sqrt{5}}=$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: [tag:roots] is about the zeros of a function (see it's tag wiki). Use [tag:arithmetic] for the (square) root operation instead (see the same tag wiki). Please read the tag wiki before applying a tag.

Comment: @AlexR "radical" is an appropriate tag here, too (in lieu of "root")

Comment: @amWhy Didn't know such an extremely localized tag existed. Thanks!

Comment: See also: [Denesting radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denesting_radicals) at Wikipedia, [Strategies to denest nested radicals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals) (and the posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/196155)).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$\sqrt{9-4\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{5+4-2\cdot 2\cdot \sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{5}-2)^{2}}=|\sqrt{5}-2|=\sqrt{5}-2$

Comment: I think for the sake of completeness one should mention that $\sqrt{(\sqrt5-2)^2}=|\sqrt{5}-2|$ $=\sqrt{5}-2$, so that one may not be tempted to state otherwise when it is hidden, e.g. if one wrote $$\sqrt{9-4\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{4-2\cdot2\cdot\sqrt{5}+5}=\sqrt{(2-\sqrt{5})^2}       \stackrel{\color{#F01C2C}{\rlap{\small\,\,!}{\displaystyle\triangle}}}{=}            2-\sqrt{5}.$$

Comment: Didn't asked to solve this for me, but ok. I always fail on this type of arithmetic (where you need split units). Anyway, thanks.

Comment: i am sorry creatur , but i hope that u wont have problems in these type of questions anymore

Comment: @avz2611 Maybe you should add a small comment of how to find the completing square easily to match up for this. Nice answer, tho. (+1)

Comment: @Workaholic How did you wizard that triangle there? :D EDIT: nvm $\color{#F01C2C}{\rlap{\small\,\,!}{\displaystyle\triangle}}$ `\color{#F01C2C}{\rlap{\small\,\,!}{\displaystyle\triangle}}`

Comment: workaholic nice edit suggested , changed it :)

Comment: @AlexR Just a combination of `\triangle` and `!` : `\stackrel{\color{#F01C2C}{\rlap{\small\,\,!}{\displaystyle\triangle}}}{=}` ;-)

Comment: @Workaholic Yeah, figured out I might as well see myself in the MathJax context menu. I almost forgot about that since answers can simply be "edited" to check.$$$$The following looks uglier but is less TeX: `\color{#F01C2C}{\displaystyle\triangle\!\!\!\small!}`: $\stackrel{\color{#F01C2C}{\displaystyle\triangle\!\!\!\small!}}=$

Answer (score 4):

This can be computed by a [Simple Denesting Rule:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/816527/242)

Here $\ 9-4\sqrt 5\ $ has norm $= 1.\:$ $\rm\ \color{blue}{subtracting\ out}\,\ \sqrt{norm}\ = 1\,\ $ yields $\,\  8-4\sqrt 5\:$

which has $\, {\rm\ \sqrt{trace}}\, =\, \sqrt{16}\, =\, 4.\ \  \rm \color{brown}{Dividing\ it\ out}\ $ of the above  yields $\ \ 2-\sqrt 5$

**Remark** $\ $ Many more worked examples are in [prior posts on this denesting rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+denesting+subtract+norm+trace)

Comment: Note: generally, as here, you may need to change the sign if you want the positive branch of sqrt.

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't even know about this simple rule!