# What method is there to denest square roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3}=1+\sqrt{3}$$

What steps would one take to get $1+\sqrt{3}$? Squaring the right side obviously gets to the expression under the square root on the left side, but I don't know how to go the other way.

Comment: Cf. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816462/simplifying-sqrt4161-72-sqrt5/816527#816527)

Comment: $(a+b)+2\sqrt{a\times b}=(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)^2$

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2076751/242) in the linked dupe for a very simple algorithm to denest such radicals. It has links to *many* worked examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Try to write $$\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3}=a+b\sqrt 3$$ and now square it. Try with assumption that $a,b$ are integers. You get $$4+2\sqrt3 = a^2+3b^2 +2ab\sqrt{3}$$

So try with $a^2+3b^2 = 4$ and $2ab = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Make the ansatz $$\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}=a+b\sqrt{3}$$.
For your work: It is $$(1+\sqrt{3})^2=1+3+2\sqrt{3}$$