# Radical problem: $\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{12}}+\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{12}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

What is the value of
$$\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{12}}+\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{12}}$$

Comment: Yeah it is correct as written and the answer is actually 4

Comment: The root at the first is for the entire first  value

Comment: Could you please provide some details about your own attempts at solving the problem?

Comment: Using a calculator, $4$. (You wanted the value, right ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $x=\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{12}}$ and $y=\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{12}}$, we have $x^2+y^2=14$ and $xy=\sqrt{7^2-2^2\cdot12}=1$, so $(x+y)^2=14+2\cdot1=16$ and thus $x+y=4,$ since $x,y$ are positive.
In general, we'd have $$\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}+\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}}=\sqrt{2a+2\sqrt{a^2-b^2c}}.$$

Comment: i.e. use $\ x+y = \sqrt{x^2\!+\!y^2 + 2xy} = \sqrt{14+2}\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Since $(2\pm\sqrt3)^2=7\pm4\sqrt3=7\pm2\sqrt{12}$,$$\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{12}}+\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{12}}=2+\sqrt3+2-\sqrt3=4.$$

Comment: How did that 2 came

Comment: @user162748 I was looking for $a,b\in\mathbb N$ such that $(a+b\sqrt3)^2=7+4\sqrt3$. But $(a+b\sqrt3)^2=a^2+3b^2+2ab\sqrt3$. So, I wanted to have $a^2+3b^2=7$ and $ab=2$ and then I took $a=2$ and $b=1$.

Comment: @user162748 You can also use this very smple [radical denesting rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/816527/242)