# How to simplify $\left({{\frac{2207+(2207^2-4)^{1/2}}2}}\right)^{1/8}$ into quadratic form?

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

The 1995 Putnam B4 asks to evaluate some infinite expression and I got this value after some computations:$$\left({{\frac{2207+(2207^2-4)^{1/2}}2}}\right)^{1/8}$$
However I am supposed to write it in form:$$\frac{a+b\sqrt{c}}{d}$$. What do I do?

(The answer is: $\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ which is the same as mine if you put in a calculator.)

Comment: Please see this link : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816462/simplifying-sqrt4161-72-sqrt5?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\,x \gt 1\,$ be the expression in question, then:

$$\require{cancel}
2x^8=2207 + \sqrt{2207^2-4} \\
(2x^8-2207)^2=2207^2-4 \\
4x^{16}-4\cdot 2207 x^8+\cancel{2207^2}=\cancel{2207^2}-4 \\
x^{16}-2207 x^8 + 1 = 0 \\
x^8 + \frac{1}{x^8}=2207 \\
\left(x^4+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)^2 = 2209 \\
x^4+\frac{1}{x^4} = 47 \\
\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2 = 49 \\
x^2+\frac{1}{x^2} = 7 \\
\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 = 9 \\
x+\frac{1}{x} = 3 \\
x^2-3x+1=0
$$

Comment: Nice trick $x^{2n} + x^{-2n} = (x^n + x^{-n})^2-2$.

Comment: @j4nbur53 Thanks. Initial clue here was to derive the equation $x^{16}-2207 x^8+1 = 0$ and recognize that the LHS is a [palindromic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial#Palindromic_and_antipalindromic_polynomials) of even degree, which then invites substitutions in powers of $x+1/x$.