# How to simplify nested radicals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, radicals, nested-radicals

How to simplify this expression?$$\sqrt{\smash[b]{18+\sqrt{260}}}-\sqrt{\smash[b]{12+\sqrt{140}}}-\sqrt{\smash[b]{20-2\sqrt{91}}},$$
which equals $0$. But how do I prove it?

**My attempt**

\begin{align}\small\sqrt{18+2\sqrt{65}} - \sqrt{12+2\sqrt{35}} - \sqrt{20-2\sqrt{91}}&\small= \sqrt{\left(\sqrt5 + \sqrt{13}\right)^2} - \sqrt{\left(\sqrt5+\sqrt7\right)^2}-\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{13}-\sqrt7\right)^2}\\&=\sqrt5+\sqrt{13}-\sqrt5-\sqrt7-\sqrt{13}+\sqrt7=0\end{align}

Pelle

Comment: Calculate $(\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{10})^2$, $(\sqrt{14}+\sqrt{10})^2$, and $(\sqrt{13}-\sqrt7)^2$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not totally clear yet, but was a good hint.

Comment: (18+(260)^0.5)^0.5 - (12+(140)^0.5)^0.5 - (20-2*(91)^0.5)^0.5
[<br/>]
(18+2*(65)^0.5)^0.5 - (12+2*(35)^0.5)^0.5 - (20-2*(91)^0.5)^0.5
[<br/>]
(5^0.5 + 13^0.5)^0.5 = 18 + 2*65^0.5
[<br/>]
(5^0.5 + 7^0.5)^0.5  = 12 + 2*35^0.5
[<br/>]
(7^0.5 - 13^0.5)^0.5 = 20 - 2*91^0.5
[<br/>]
5^0.5 + 13^0.5 - 5^0.5 - 7^0.5 - 7^0.5 + 13^0.5
[<br/>]
0

Comment: Unreadable, Pelle. If you're going to use this site, it would be a really good idea to read up on how to format mathematics here. The help menu might get you started on that.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Yeah. Have problem with the formatting :-).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hope it is better now.

Comment: Your attempt is correct.

Comment: Try https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816462/simplifying-sqrt4161-72-sqrt5/816527#816527