# How to simplify surd expressions such as this?

Tags: radicals

I am having trouble with questions like these:

$$\sqrt{x-y\sqrt z}$$

Or as an example:

$$\sqrt{17-12\sqrt2}$$

I cannot see how to go about this. I have tried squaring the expression, which ends up giving $\sqrt{289}-\sqrt{288}$, but I do not know where to go from here.

Can anybody help?

Comment: $\sqrt{17-12\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{17-2\sqrt{9}\sqrt{8}}=\sqrt{(3-2\sqrt{2})^2}=3-2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: $17=(2\sqrt2)^2+3^2$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplifying $\sqrt[4]{161-72 \sqrt{5}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816462/simplifying-sqrt4161-72-sqrt5)  This includes two general approaches for such problems.

Comment: The problem you have suggested I look at gives me a good start - however I come upon a roadblock, because I get the expressions a^2+b^2=17, and 2ab = 12. a^2 + 2b^2 can only be factorised into (a+b(√2))*(a-b(√2)), which doesn't help me when 2ab = 12.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find how $\sqrt{x-y\sqrt{z}}$ could be a perfect square.

We assume

$$x-y\sqrt z=(a-b\sqrt z)^2=a^2+b^2z-2ab\sqrt z$$ where $a,b$ are rational.

Then we need to solve

$$\begin{cases}a^2+b^2z=x,\\2ab=y\end{cases}.$$

Multiplying by $a^2$,

$$a^4-a^2x+a^2b^2z=a^4-a^2x+\frac{y^2}4z=0.$$

This equation has a rational solution if the discriminant

$$\Delta=x^2-y^2z$$

is a perfect square, and one of the roots in $a^2$ is a perfect square

$$\frac{x\pm\sqrt\Delta}2.$$

---

With the given example,

$$\Delta=1,\\\frac{17\pm1}2=8,9.$$