# Minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

I am trying to determine the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and explain why does it have degree $4$.

I found that the minimal polynomial is $f(x)=x^4-2x^2-1$. It is monic, and $f(\alpha)=0$. It is also irreducible as the only possible roots are $\pm 1$, however, $f(\pm 1)\ne 0$. Now, I am trying to explain why does it have degree $4$, and here is what I got:

- The degree is not $1$ as $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$.
- The degree is not $2$ as if it was then $\alpha ^2+b \alpha +c=0$ for some $b,c \in  \mathbb{Q}$. Then

$1+\sqrt{2}+(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})b+c=0\implies \sqrt{2} (b^2+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}} b)=c^2+2c-b^2-1$.

The right hand side is in $\mathbb{Q}$, but the left isn’t, which is a contradiction.

I am stuck at showing that the degree is not $3$ though. If it was three then I think that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=3$, and this should lead us at a contraction. I am not sure how to show that.

Comment: Is $\sqrt{\sqrt 2+1}$ [really](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E4-2x-1%3D0%2Cx%3Dsqrt%28sqrt%282%29%2B1%29) the root of $x^4-2x-1$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Looks like a typo. It should be $x^4-2x^2-1$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash sorry I meant $x^4-2x^2-1$

Comment: "It is also irreducible as the only possible roots are $\pm 1$" - that only rules out linear factors, you need to rule out quadratic factors too (or notice $f(x+1)$ satisfies conditions of Eisenstein criterion).

Comment: By far the simplest way to do this: Apply Eisenstein's criterion to $f(x+1)=x^4+4x^3+4x^2-2$.

Comment: How do you know the left side isn't in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @mr_e_man I think it would be in $\mathbb{Q}$ only if $b=0$, but if $b=0$, then $0=\alpha^2+b\alpha+c=\alpha^2+c$, and thus $c=-(1+\sqrt{2})$, but $c\in \mathbb{Q}$. Is that right?

Comment: For comparison, consider $$\sqrt2\big((1)^2+\sqrt{3-2\sqrt2}\;(1)\big)=2$$ which is in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: You need to prove that $\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}$ is not in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$.

Comment: So, suppose $(x+y\sqrt2)^2=1+\sqrt2$ for some rational $x,y$. That means $$x^2+2y^2=1,\quad2xy=1.$$ Can you show that this is impossible?

Comment: @mr_e_man I was about to write this :), I tried solving this system but it only has complex solutions. So $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: You have already proved that the polynomial has no linear factor (and hence no cubic factor as well). You can also observe that if $a$ is a root of polynomial then $-a$ is also a root and hence if it has a quadratic factor then we must have the polynomial expressed as $(x^2+px+q)(x^2-px+q)$. Derive an obvious contradiction now.

Comment: how do you conclude that $f$ is not reducible? why 1 and -1 ?

Comment: @NotaChoice see proposition 9.4.11 in Dummit and Foote, if you don’t have the book, please let me know so that I write the proposition for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \hookrightarrow\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$ : since $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q}]=2$, then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}) : \mathbb{Q}]$ is dividible by $2$, so the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ cannot have degree $3$.

Answer (score 1):

If $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=3$, then $\alpha$ would be the zero of a polynomial $p$ of degree $3$. $p$ would divide $f$. A contradiction as you proved that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: No, they didn't prove that $f$ is irreducible. The degree $2$ case needs more work.

Comment: @mr_e_man The OP wrote and proved that $\alpha$ is not of degree $2$.

Comment: Are you referring to the comments, or the original question?

Comment: @mr_e_man Have you read the original question?

Comment: The question says "The right hand side is in $\mathbb Q$, but the left isn’t, which is a contradiction." This reasoning is wrong, or incomplete. Why isn't the left side in $\mathbb Q$?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but I always wanted to understand something :

Let $\alpha= \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ , the only way to get rid of the square root is to square ; $\alpha^2= 1+\sqrt{2}\ \ $ then $\sqrt{2}= \alpha^2 -1$ so, again squaring ; $2= (\alpha^2 -1)^2= \alpha^4- 2\alpha^2+ 1$ , meaning that $\alpha$ is a root of $$x^4-2x^2-1$$
Now here is the argument that I want you to confirm whether it is valid or not :
Since we arrived to that polynomial just by 'getting rid of the square roots' in a 'minimal' way, i.e. this is the polynomial with the smallest degree we can have if we try to find a polynomial with rational coefficients. ( why? because we were just getting rid of the radicals ), and this polynomial is irreducible, then $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]= 4$ .

It seems that this argument is not quite valid because of cubics, or polynomials of degree $3$. I wonder if there is a way, a constructive way, for any root of a cubic to find immediately that polynomial, so that to make this argument valid every time?

I mean starting with $\alpha$ , and just getting rid of the radicals to arrive to the minimal polynomial, which will be of degree $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, or more ...

Comment: This should possibly have been a new question, but I try and explain it anyway. The trouble is that something like the following may happen. Do the same with $\beta=\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}$. You get $\beta^2=3+2\sqrt2$ and then 
$$0=(\beta^2-3)^2-8=\beta^4-6\beta^2+1.$$
But 
$$x^4-6x^2+1=(x^4-2x^2+1)-4x^2=(x^2-1)^2-(2x)^2$$
is the difference of two squares and hence factors as $(x^2-2x-1)(x^2+2x-1)$.

I was mean and set this up. The explanation is that 
$$(1+\sqrt2)^2=3+2\sqrt2,$$
so we really had $\beta=\alpha^2$. Or, phrased differently, it was possible to denest the square root.

Comment: [More serious denesting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/816462/11619).

Comment: Be prepared for this to get deleted. You really shouldn't post follow up questions as answers.

Comment: still the polynomial $x^4-2x^2-1$ is irreducible, only then I can make the conclusion. The question is how I can guarantee that there is no cubic.

Comment: I am confused actually. The original question asks to explain why the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $4$ : the person asking found that $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$ and that $p(x)$ is irreducible and has degree $4$. Isn't this enough as a justification? What does he want to explain exactly?

Comment: And my question is another idea actually I will probably post it later

Comment: Sorry, I mistook you for the OP. Yeah, you really should ask another question. The OP's argument excluding quadratic polynomials is not entirely convincing. And the cubic factors were eliminated by eliminating linear factors.