# Weird square root problem: Is the claim $\sqrt{a + \sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \implies \sqrt{a - \sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}$ true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Given the equation below:
$$\sqrt{a+\sqrt b}=\sqrt x+\sqrt y$$
Show that:
$$\sqrt{a-\sqrt b}=\sqrt x-\sqrt y$$

I saw the above problem. However, I can't figure out how to manipulate the above. Furthermore, are these equations even true? If $a=21$, $b=16$, $x=9$ and $y=4$ then the other equation does not hold true. Is the question wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're right, the claim is wrong as is.

Comment: Something more might be given, like $x$ and $y$ are not perfect squares...

Comment: *Where* did you see that?

Comment: I think this has something to do with equating irrational and rational parts of an equation, so DS's guess is probably correct.

Comment: I've attached the exact question

Comment: For the second part, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/196155/42969

Comment: We can write (see ["Is it doable?"](https://brownmath.com/alge/nestrad.htm)) 
 $\sqrt{a\pm\sqrt b}=\sqrt x\pm\sqrt y$ if and only if $a>0$ and $a^2-b$ is a perfect square. In this case $a=84$ and $b=16^2\cdot17=4352$, but $a^2-b=2704=52^2$, so the second problem is indeed wrong.

Comment: Notice that your question does not clearly tell what you want. The above is not a theorem or a law. It is a special case for some variables.

Comment: @user170231 I disagree with your "if and only if". For example, if we were not restricted to integers, then we could adjust your $x, y$ values arbitrarily to fit the $+$ condition, but clearly the $-$ condition will be false.

Comment: @CalvinLin Not *mine*, I was paraphrasing from the provided link :) The author does explicitly say $x,y\in\Bbb Q$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/816527/242) for a simple method to denest sqrts.

Answer (score 3):

The given equation is:

$$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$$

Here we have to consider two cases.
$\mathbf{CASE-I}$
If $b$ is not a perfect square then after squaring both sides
${(\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}})}^2={(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})}^2
\Rightarrow a+\sqrt{b}=x+y+2 \sqrt{xy}
\Rightarrow a-x-y=2 \sqrt{xy}-\sqrt{b}$

As $a-x-y$ is an integer so $2 \sqrt{xy}-\sqrt{b}$ should also be an integer. But they are not perfect squares so they are same thus
$2 \sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{b}$
Hence $a-\sqrt{b}=x+y-2 \sqrt{xy}$
So $\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$

$\mathbf{CASE-II}$

If $b$ is a perfect square then after squaring both sides
${(\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}})}^2={(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})}^2
\Rightarrow a+\sqrt{b}=x+y+2 \sqrt{xy}$
As $b$ is a perfect square so as $xy$.
Now,
$a+\sqrt{b}-2 \sqrt{xy}=x+y-2 \sqrt{xy}
\Rightarrow \sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}-2 \sqrt{xy}}
      =\sqrt{x+y-2 \sqrt{xy}}
      =\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$
To get the form $\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}$ we need to have $b= xy$ which is not true in your example

Comment: You need to enclose your LaTeX in dollar signs (\$) on this site.

Comment: For case 1, you're also making the assumption that $a, b, x, y$ are integers (or something similar, which isn't stated explicitly by OP. )$\quad$ Without that assumption, your "$a - x - y$ is an integer" no longer holds.

Answer (score 1):

As several of the other comments have stated, the claim is wrong in general. I believe the idea here is that by choosing **appropriate** $x$ and $y$, we **may** be able to simplify an expression of the form $\sqrt{p+q\sqrt{r}}$.

Note that squaring both sides of the given equation yields

$$\begin{align}
a + \sqrt{b} &= x + y + 2\sqrt{xy} \\[2mm]
&= x + y + \sqrt{4xy}
\end{align}$$

Now if we can find naturals $x$ and $y$ such that $\; a = x + y \;$ and $\; b = 4xy \;$ then we would be able to simplify $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$.

In particular, to simplify the given $\sqrt{84+16\sqrt{17}}$ we first note that we can factor out a 2 and rewrite as $2\sqrt{21+4\sqrt{17}} = 2\sqrt{21+\sqrt{4 \cdot 68}}$; thus we are looking for natural solutions to the system $x+y=21$ and $xy=68$.

This is relatively straightforward:

$$\begin{align}
(x-y)^2 &= (x+y)^2 - 4xy \\[2mm]
&= 21^2 - 4(68) \\[2mm]
&= 169 \\[2mm]
x-y &= 13
\end{align}$$

which then combining with $x+y=21$ easily yields $x=17$ and $y=4$.

Thus

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{84+16\sqrt{17}} &= 2\sqrt{21+4\sqrt{17}} \\[2mm]
&= 2 \left( \sqrt{17} + \sqrt{4} \right) \\[2mm]
&= 4 + 2\sqrt{17}
\end{align}$$

Addendum:

Initially I felt the claim was useless in answering the second part; however after I wrote the above solution I realized it could be used in the following way: if we let, as above, $a = x + y$ and $b = 4xy$, then

$$\begin{align}
a - \sqrt{b} &= x + y - \sqrt{4xy} \\[2mm]
&= x + y - 2\sqrt{xy} \\[2mm]
&= \left( \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} \right)^2
\end{align}$$

and therefore

$$\begin{align}
x - y &= \left( \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \right) \left( \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} \right) \\[2mm]
&= \left( \sqrt{a + \sqrt{b}} \right) \left( \sqrt{a - \sqrt{b}} \right) \\[2mm]
&= \sqrt{a^2 - b}
\end{align}$$

which would then yield the same $x-y=13$ as above.

Comment: I added a straightforward way to seeing why $ \sqrt{a^2 - b} = x-y$ is the necessary and sufficient condition.  $\quad$ Note that you can simplify your approach of finding $x, y$ by observing that they are the solutions to $X^2 - aX + b/4 = 0 $.

Answer (score 1):

If we make the assumption that $a, b, x, y$ are integers (or even rational), then see Wtsm's solution (with slight modifications). Otherwise, read on.

---

**Lemma:** The claim is true iff $ \sqrt{a^2 - b} = x-y$.

**Proof:** Given that condition, $ \sqrt{a - \sqrt{b}} = \frac{ \sqrt{ a^2 - b } } { \sqrt{ a - \sqrt{b} }} = \frac{ x-y}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} } = \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} $.
The converse follows by multiplying the 2 equations and using the same algebraic manipulation.

**Corollary:** For a given $a, b$, if $x, y$ are not restricted to integers, then we can find numerous solutions sets to $ \sqrt{ a + \sqrt{b} } = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$, but only one of them will also satisfy $  \sqrt{a^2 - b} = x-y$.
In particular, for your chosen values of $a=21$, $b=16$, $x=9$ and $y=4$, since $a^2 - b = 425 \neq 25 = (x-y)^2$, so the conclusion will not hold.

Answer (score -2):

The claim is true by isomorphism: that is you can replace $\sqrt b$ by $-\sqrt b$ as long as $by$ or $bx$ is itself a square.